# How do I assign a function to a button from another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

I have a `Map` component where I created a function to get the user's current location. I have imported this map component into a larger `RetailLocations` component. I want to assign the `handleClick()` function created in the `Map` component to a button in the `RetailLocations` component. The relevant code:

`Map Component code:`

```
    const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });
    const location = useGeoLocation();
    const mapRef = useRef();
    
    const ZOOM_LEVEL = 20;

    

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        if (location.loaded) {
            mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo(
                [location.coordinates.lat, location.coordinates.lng],
                ZOOM_LEVEL,
                { animate: true }
            );  
        } 
    };



    return <>
        <MapContainer
            center={center}
            zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL}
            ref={mapRef}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            className={style.mapContainer}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />
            {location.loaded && (
                <Marker position={[ location.coordinates.lat, location.coordinates.lng ]}></Marker>
            )}
        </MapContainer>
    </>;
};

export default Map;
```

`This is the RetailLocations component's relevant code:`

```
import Map from './Map';
....
<button
    className={style.locationBtn}
    onClick={handleClick}
>My Location</button>
....
```

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I feel like this is one of these cases where the `Map` component should probably subscribe to some event source (e.g. an observable), that emits coordinates and then you simply emit those "coordinates events" from other places in the app.

Comment: Components cannot return additional variables. But why not simply move the handleClick logic to `RetailLocations`?

Answer (score 1):

you should read this. from pluralsight: Components are an integral part of React. Each React application consists of several components, and each component may require user interaction that triggers various actions.
To achieve user interactivity, we can call functions and methods to accomplish specific operations in React. We pass data from parent to child or child to parent components using these actions.
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-reference-a-function-in-another-component

Answer (score 1):

Use forwardRef and useImperativeHandle hooks to access method inside a functional component.

Map component:

```js
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react'

const Map = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  ...

  const handleClick = (e) => {
      if (location.loaded) {
          mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo(
              [location.coordinates.lat, location.coordinates.lng],
              ZOOM_LEVEL,
              { animate: true }
          );  
      } 
  };

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({ handleClick }),
    [handleClick]
  );

  return <>
     <MapContainer
         center={center}
         zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL}
         ref={mapRef}
         scrollWheelZoom={false}
         className={style.mapContainer}
     >
         <TileLayer
             attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
             url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
         />
         {location.loaded && (
             <Marker position={[ location.coordinates.lat, location.coordinates.lng ]}></Marker>
         )}
     </MapContainer>
  </>;
})
```

RetailLocations component:

```js
import Map from './Map';
import { useRef } from 'react';
....

const RetailLocations = () => {

   const ref = useRef()
   
   return <>
     <Map ref={ref} />
     <button 
         className={style.locationBtn}
         onClick={(e) => ref.current.handleClick(e)}>
       My Location
     </button>
   </>
}

....
```

Comment: Thanks. The only caveat is now I get this error: Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()